# Network card seems to be active but config file is missing?

Tags: networking, systemd, udev

I have a CentOS 7 virtual machine with an internal network as well as 2 bridged connections, I am unable to find the config file for the third network card. Any ideas where it could be? or what the issue is.

I have added 2 images. [image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: What do you mean by "third network card"? Do you mean `enp0s9`?

Comment: yes that is the one which is not visible in network-scripts and I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

You could delve into this by looking for the MAC address with `grep "08:00:27:9b:e5:49" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*`, and the interface name itself.  I'm guessing it gets configured along with something else.

Note that those files are not mandatory, they're just conveniences.  An interface could be configured without them.

Comment: Two other means on CentOS 7 would be `networkd` or `NetworkManager` neither of which strictly speaking must use `network-scripts` (although `NetworkManager` could potentially be).

Comment: grep "08:00:27:9b:e5:49" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/* doesn't return anything, I am still stuck unfortunately. I am required to bond enp0s8 and enp0s9 which is why I require the config file for both.

Comment: Sounds like an **[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)**.  Your real issue is that you are "required to bond enp0s8 and enp0s9", not that you can't find a config file.  If you think there should be one to facilitate this, create it.